# How to read the My roles from the Privileged Identity Management in Microsoft Entry Id using Microsoft Graph Powershell modules?

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication, authorization

I have access to the following screen through the Azure Portal:
[image]

And I need to activate 5 roles. The GUI is atrocious, it does not allow activating multiple roles at ones.

I would like to script this and the first task for me is to read the content of this screen programmatically.

I specifically want to use the most recent [Microsoft Graph Powershell modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/azuread-msoline-cmdlet-map?view=graph-powershell-1.0).

But I did not advance too far. I can do `Connect-MgGraph` and then I figured I need to call
`Get-MgBetaPrivilegedAccessResource -PrivilegedAccessId AzureResources`, but it fails:

```
Get-MgBetaPrivilegedAccessResource_List: {"errorCode":"PermissionScopeNotGranted","message":"Authorization failed due to missing permission scope PrivilegedAccess.Read.AzureResources,PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureResources.","instanceAnnotations":[]}

Status: 403 (Forbidden)
ErrorCode: UnknownError
Date: 2023-12-04T18:24:46

Headers:
Cache-Control                 : private
Transfer-Encoding             : chunked
Vary                          : Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security     : max-age=31536000
request-id                    : 91036c22-82da-4c5b-8d18-ed77dd9902f8
client-request-id             : 775dd1f0-cbf0-45cd-899b-4a953a70a8fc
x-ms-ags-diagnostic           : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Canada Central","Slice":"E","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"002","RoleInstance":"YT2PEPF00000162"}}
Date                          : Mon, 04 Dec 2023 18:24:45 GMT
```

I tried to run `Connect-MgGraph -Scopes PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureResources`, but it says I need an admin access for that. I do not have it. So, this is a dead end.

Tried to run `Get-MgBetaPrivilegedAccessResource -PrivilegedAccessId AzureResources -Filter "Type eq 'subscription' And DisplayName eq 'SUBSCRIPTION-I-CAN-ACCESS'"`, but it fails with the same exact error.

How can this be done?

P.S.

Please, do not propose solutions using AzureADPreview and msal.ps - I specifically want to use the most recent and non obsolete modules.

**EDIT 1**

[image]

**EDIT 2**

[image]

**EDIT 3**

Here is the suggested approach (thank you Sridevi):

```
$ScopeTypes = @('resourcegroup', 'subscription')

Connect-AzAccount
Get-AzRoleEligibilitySchedule -Scope "/" -Filter "asTarget()" `
| Where-Object { $ScopeTypes -contains $_.ScopeType } `
| Group-Object RoleDefinitionDisplayName, Scope `
| Select-Object @{ Expression = { $_.group[0] } ; Label = 'Item' } `
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty item `
| ForEach-Object {
    $p = @{
        Name                      = (New-Guid).Guid
        Scope                     = $_.Scope
        PrincipalId               = $_.PrincipalId
        RoleDefinitionId          = $_.RoleDefinitionId
        ScheduleInfoStartDateTime = Get-Date -Format o
    }
    
    New-AzRoleAssignmentScheduleRequest @p -ExpirationDuration PT8H -ExpirationType AfterDuration -RequestType SelfActivate -Justification "work"
}
```

The `Get-AzRoleEligibilitySchedule` indeed returns My Roles, however, `New-AzRoleAssignmentScheduleRequest` fails with the same error:

```
New-AzRoleAssignmentScheduleRequest_CreateExpanded: C:\dayforce\scripts\pim.ps1:28
Line |
  28 |      New-AzRoleAssignmentScheduleRequest @p -ExpirationDuration PT8H - …
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The requestor a...e does not have permissions for this request. Please use
     | $filter=asTarget() to filter on the requestor's assignments.
```

I checked and `a...e` is my user's object id. And I certainly can activate the roles in the browser. But when running these commands on the console - they fail.

However, this question is about reading My Roles, so it is done and I will post another question on how to activate them.

Comment: Could you include what **Microsoft Entra** roles your signed-in user has?

Comment: On the high level these roles allow me access that screen and activate the roles. I can provide exact roles once I figure out how to get this information. If you know of a code I can run to get it - please share and I will run it.

Comment: From portal, you can select that user -> Assigned roles -> Active assignments like this https://i.imgur.com/WEPSqWR.png

Comment: You can run `Get-MgBetaRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignment -Filter  " principalId eq 'userObjId'"` to get those details via PowerShell.

Comment: Both the portal and the command line return empty list - apparently I have none. I do not know the meaning of it, I can certainly access that screen and activate the roles.

Comment: But while connecting to Azure account with `Connect-MgGraph`, you need to have proper Microsoft Entra role or permission to perform operation via Microsoft Graph.

Comment: I agree, but the command you showed to me (thank you) does not show anything, so it must be something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256162/discussion-between-sridevi-and-mark).

Comment: You need to run `Connect-AzAccount` and run `Az` module commands to retrieve those eligible assignments list of signed-in user under Azure Resources.

Comment: Does it mean the solution to this question does not advance me in the direction of scripting the activation of these roles? If you know the concrete `Az` command to run - please share.

Comment: I'm currently checking the `Az` command, will add the answer once I'm successful in retrieving the roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have below Eligible assignments in `My roles` tab of **signed-in** user under Azure Resources:

[image]

To get these details via PowerShell, I ran below **`Az`** commands and got response successfully like this:

```
Connect-AzAccount -SubscriptionId "xxxxxxx"
Get-AzRoleEligibilitySchedule -Scope "/" -Filter "asTarget()" | Select-Object "RoleDefinitionDisplayName","ScopeType", "ScopeDisplayName","PrincipalDisplayName"
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **activate** the first 5 eligible assignments, I ran below updated PowerShell script:

```
# Retrieve eligible assignments
$eligibleAssignments = Get-AzRoleEligibilitySchedule -Scope "/" -Filter "asTarget()" | Select-Object "RoleDefinitionId", "Scope", "PrincipalId" | Select -First 5

# Activate eligible assignments
foreach ($assignment in $eligibleAssignments) {
    $roleDefinitionId = $assignment.RoleDefinitionId
    $scope = $assignment.Scope
    $principalId = $assignment.PrincipalId
    $guid = (New-Guid).Guid
    $startTime = Get-Date -Format o 
    
    New-AzRoleAssignmentScheduleRequest -Name $guid -Scope $scope -ExpirationDuration PT1H -ExpirationType AfterDuration -PrincipalId $principalId -RequestType SelfActivate -RoleDefinitionId $roleDefinitionId -ScheduleInfoStartDateTime $startTime -Justification "demo purpose"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal after some time where roles **activated** successfully as below:

[image]

Comment: I am marking it as answer to the question of how to read My Roles, because this is what I am asking here and you did it. But activation does not work for me. I will post a separate question about it.

Comment: Would you be able to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77627964/how-to-activate-my-roles-in-the-privileged-identity-management-in-azure-from-con ?

Comment: FYI, I answered my own question. Found the reason I could not activate my roles.