# How to activate My Roles in the Privileged Identity Management in Azure from console?

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication, authorization

This question is a continuation of [How to read the My roles from the Privileged Identity Management in Microsoft Entry Id using Microsoft Graph Powershell modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77601811/how-to-read-the-my-roles-from-the-privileged-identity-management-in-microsoft-en)

In the aforementioned question I learned how to read My Roles:

```
$ScopeTypes=@('subscription','resourcegroup')
Connect-AzAccount > $null
Get-AzRoleEligibilitySchedule -Scope "/" -Filter "asTarget()" `
| Where-Object { $ScopeTypes -contains $_.ScopeType } `
| Group-Object RoleDefinitionDisplayName, Scope `
| Select-Object @{ Expression = { $_.group[0] } ; Label = 'Item' } `
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty item `
| Format-Table RoleDefinitionDisplayName, ScopeDisplayName, ScopeType
```

And it works great:

```
RoleDefinitionDisplayName                  ScopeDisplayName   ScopeType
-------------------------                  ----------------   ---------
Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster User Role ...                resourcegroup
Cognitive Services Contributor             ...                subscription
Contributor                                ...                resourcegroup
Contributor                                ...                resourcegroup
Owner                                      ...                resourcegroup
Reader                                     ...                subscription
Reader                                     ...                subscription
```

Now I would like to activate them.

I tried the following code:

```
$ScopeTypes = @('resourcegroup', 'subscription')

Connect-AzAccount > $null
Get-AzRoleEligibilitySchedule -Scope "/" -Filter "asTarget()" `
| Where-Object { $ScopeTypes -contains $_.ScopeType } `
| Group-Object RoleDefinitionDisplayName, Scope `
| Select-Object @{ Expression = { $_.group[0] } ; Label = 'Item' } `
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty item `
| ForEach-Object {
    $p = @{
        Name                      = (New-Guid).Guid
        Scope                     = $_.Scope
        PrincipalId               = $_.PrincipalId
        RoleDefinitionId          = $_.RoleDefinitionId
        ScheduleInfoStartDateTime = Get-Date -Format o
    }
    
    New-AzRoleAssignmentScheduleRequest @p -ExpirationDuration PT8H -ExpirationType AfterDuration -RequestType SelfActivate -Justification "work"
}
```

Unfortunately, all the attempts fail with the same error:

```
New-AzRoleAssignmentScheduleRequest_CreateExpanded: C:\dayforce\scripts\pim.ps1:28
Line |
  28 |      New-AzRoleAssignmentScheduleRequest @p -ExpirationDuration PT8H - …
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The requestor a...e does not have permissions for this request. Please use
     | $filter=asTarget() to filter on the requestor's assignments.
```

Where `a...e` is indeed my object Id. I have no problems activating these roles in the browser as this user, but it does not work on the console.

Comment: Similar ask has been discussed here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77252524/activate-pim-role-for-azure-resources-via-rest-powershell

Comment: I have not noticed more details that already are present in my question. I seem to do everything right and yet get an error. Or have I missed anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what is wrong. `PrincipalId` reported by `Get-AzRoleEligibilitySchedule` is the id of an AAD **group** in my case. However, when activating the role one must pass the user's own object Id, rather than that of an AAD group the user may belong to.

Once I changed the code to pass my own object Id instead of the `PrincipalId` reported by `Get-AzRoleEligibilitySchedule` - it all started to work.